# How can I create a dblink from Postgresql 8.3 to SQL Server (2000 and 2008)?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, dblink, postgresql-8.3

I have a Postgresql database that need to read data from two SQL Servers (one SQL Server 2000 and one SQL Server 2008).

I want to setup two dblinks to the SQL Servers.

After googling, foruming, reading documentation, I struggle to find something production ready.

What tool can I use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to install pl/perlu and [dbilink](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/dbi-link) which lets you use any of Perl's drivers. This would be straightforward enough on a unix-based system, but is probably somewhere around the difficult/impractical/painful end of things on Windows.

Or, upgrade and try one of the [foreign-data-wrappers](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers#odbc_fdw) in recent releases of PostgreSQL. Upgrading is [probably worthwhile anyway](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/), since 8.3 is near end-of-life and the 9 series should have some major improvements (particularly if PG is on Windows).

Or, push the data from the SQL Server end - you can make PostgreSQL available over ODBC.